# System.Text.Json Deserialize Null Value

Tags: json

Is it possible to write the following function as a single line?

```
using System.Text.Json;

private MyClass GetClaimAsMyClass()
{
    // The claim might not exist!
    Claim claim = User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == "myclaimtype");
    return claim == null ? null : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(claim.value);
}
```

In other words, is there a way to execute JsonSerializer.Deserialize passing in a null string and get a null value back (without error)?

For example, I'd like to do this:

```
return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.type == "myclaimtype")?.Value)
```

Or maybe there's some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's something in JsonSerializeOptions that I've not been able to find, but in lieu of that, I've taken the following approach:

Create a 'wrapper' around the JsonSerializer and put that in the System.Text.Json namespace, (can't create extension as its a static class):

```
namespace System.Text.Json
{
    public static class JsonNullSerializer
    {
        public static T Deserialize<T>(string value)
            => string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)
               ? default
               : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using System.Text.Json;

private MyClass GetClaimAsMyClass()
    => JsonNullSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(
           User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == "myclaimtype")?.Value);
```